# Automating a task with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I need to make a script that performs a variety of tasks that are not super complex. For example, clicking buttons and filling input fields. What i am trying to build is a way to automate a password reset functionality that is already in place, but i don't know how to begin. Can this sort of thing be done in javascript/jquery or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: ...sounds a bit nefarious....why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DelightedD0D haha no nothing nefarious is going on! There is a system in place to reset a password and someone made an error and made a whole bunch of accounts with incorrect passwords. So im trying to automate a way to reset them without having to spend majority of my day clicking away.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like Selenium: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

It allows you to create simple to complex tasks easily.
There are many tools like this but Selenium is free, easy to understand, and there is a huge community.

Comment: Perfect! I have never really done automation so i will check this out thank you!

Comment: You will see that this tool is super-easy to go with !  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could be looking for this kinda tool: https://ghostinspector.com/

Otherwise if you wanna get your hands dirty with some code you need to look into http://phantomjs.org/, its a headless browser for exactly that stuff